# Show that there is a polynomial such that P(n) is not prime

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let m and n be a integer. Show that for all values of n there is a polynomial such that P(n) equals toma prime number. For instance for the polynomial $$x^{2}+1$$ for x=1 the result is equal to 2. Question is finding a polynomal that is not equals to a prime number for all values of x.

Comment: What is the purpose of $m$? Do ask if for each $n$ there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $P(n)$ is not prime or if there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $P(n)$ is not prime for all $n$?

Comment: it has no purpose it is extra

Comment: $p(x) = x^2$ never produces prime numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the question is the following - Is there a polynomial $P(x)$ such that for any integer $n$, $P(n)$ is not prime? - yes, there are very simple examples: $P(x)=4x$ or $P(x)=x^2$ would both do the job.